# Top of WKWebViewcontent is clipped under NSToolbar in Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, macos, appkit, mac-catalyst

I have a catalyst app that has a WKWebView in a UINavigationController. On iOS, I have a navigation bar above the Web View, like so:
[image: [Image]]

However, on macOS, I've hidden the Navigation Bar and instead display an NSToolbar. However, the WebView's contents are clipped below the Toolbar:
[image: [Image]]

(Note that after scrolling the web view down, the content is no longer clipped)

How can I set the WKWebView so that the content isn't clipped below the toolbar?

Comment: Are you constraining to the safe-area?

Comment: No. I have the View Controller’s view set as the web view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around wit an AppKit bridge in my Catalyst app, I determined what appears to be the cause of the problem: the `styleMask` for Catalyst windows contains `.fullSizeContentView`, which is used to make the view within an `NSWindow` extend under the titlebar/toolbar (this is what enables the translucent toolbar in apps like Safari). For whatever reason, `WKWebView` doesn't deal with it properly, and that's what's causing the content to be clipped.

As a workaround, I add an observer for `NSWindow.didBecomeMainNotification` in a method in the AppKit bundle that runs when the app is first launched (for my use case, I'm only worrying about the main window). As a result, the following method gets called when a window becomes the app's "main" window:

```
    @objc func setWindow(_ sender: Notification) {
        if let w = sender.object as? NSWindow {
            if w.styleMask.contains(.fullSizeContentView){
                var sm = w.styleMask
                sm.remove(.fullSizeContentView)
                w.styleMask = sm
            }
        }
    }
```

This removes `.fullSizeContentView` from the window's `styleMask`, and as a result, the `WKWebView`'s content is no longer clipped when it first appears.

I should note that the workaround isn't perfect - you won't have the translucency effect under the toolbar anymore.

If you'd like to add an AppKit Bundle to a Catalyst app, the following resources should be helpful

https://crunchybagel.com/disabling-the-mac-zoom-maximise-button-in-catalyst/ 
https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit

If you're still confused, I recommend playing with the demo project below that I found:
https://github.com/noahsark769/CatalystPlayground